# Wrapping ASP Form inside Bootstrap Layout

Tags: css, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have built a form in HTML 5 that is in a modal window and wrapped in Bootstrap and the layout is perfect. I have the need to use another modal window, however instead of the form being built in HTML 5 I need to place and iframe in the modal and display and asp form. I have wrapped everything identically in Bootstrap, but for some reason the label next to my form control displays on top and not next to. I'm stumped, I have played with CSS for two days now trying to figure out why. Thoughts?

HTML CODE FOR FORM THAT LAYS OUT PERFECT

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:100%">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Observation Form</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="well form-horizontal" action=javascript:createNewObservation() method="post" id="observationForm">
                    <fieldset>
                        <!-- Form Name -->

                        <!-- Enter Building -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Building</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                                    <select id="formBuilding" name="formBuilding" class="form-control selectpicker" required></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

IMAGE FOR PERFECT LAYOUT

[image]

ASP CODE WRAPPED IN IFRAME THAT IS DISPLAYING IN MODAL

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" class="well form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>File Upload Form</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Choose File</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                    <asp:FileUpload class="form-control" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" style="width:50%" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="site" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="dateobserved" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="guid" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="username" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

IMAGE FOR INCORRECT LAYOUT

[image]

Comment: Check out https://bootstrap.build/app. See the `forms > Horizontal form` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems like you need to set a width to the iframe 'cause the modal size isn't changing. Try set width to 100% for the iframe